# Is it possible to extend ChatMessage to store custom information

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm looking for a possibility to extend ChatMessage objects to store custom information. For objects of type message its possible by implementing scheme extension. According to documentation its not supported for chat message. I already tried this, but got an *UnknownError*. Does anyone has an idea how i can make this work? Or are there other possibilies to get custom information into a chat message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no possibility and you can raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)